# Set programmatically product price to get it displayed everywhere in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have a php cron job that is updating product information from a 3rd party vendor.  These changes can be price, sale price, stock, etc.

I have everything running except when I go to put a product on sale via the following code:

```
 update_post_meta( $product_id, '_sale_price', $sale_price );
 update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $sale_price );
```

the product is updated correctly and shows the sale price in the product on the website and the product admin. When I go to use one of the shortcodes for woocommerce to display products on sale it does NOT pull back what was updated via the above code, ONLY if it was done through the admin panel.

```
[products limit="24" columns="4" on_sale="true" ]
```

So my code is not doing something woocommerce does, but I have no idea what it is I am missing.  My only fix so far I have found is to remove the sale price in the admin panel->save and then add it back->and save again.  Since there are 18,000+ variations on 3,000+ products this is not something that can be done by hand.

As an aside: I had this problem with WP all import too when we imported vis csv file feeds.

Any ideas or thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Woocommerce caches the product data for performance, so directly updating the meta will not update the cache. Use of the CRUD methods in LoicTheAztec's answer will.

Comment: @PeterHvD Unfortunately CRUD is not working inside my CRON job. Woocommerce throws an error.

Answer (score 5):

The best way should be to use [CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) introduced with Woocommerce 3… But as it is in a cron job, I am not sure that it will work. Anyway try the following:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Product object
$product = new WC_Product( $product_id );

// Set product prices
$product->set_sale_price( $sale_price );
$product->set_price( $price );

// Save data and update caches
$product->save();
```

Now depending on the product type, you might be need to call the product object instance differently…

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to use CRUD inside the cron job.  Woocommerce throws an error in woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php on line 149 when it attempts to read the product information that was passed to it.  Not sure how else to address this, I am thinking maybe I can put sale items into their own category and display that.

Comment: You're going to have a problem in the future then as Woocommerce [announced](https://wptavern.com/woocommerce-custom-product-tables-plugin-now-in-beta-boasts-30-faster-page-loads) recently that they intend to move everything over to custom tables, which is why they implemented CRUD in the first place.

Comment: @PeterHvD This is not for now, there is still a long time before that happen.

Comment: CRUD is failing inside a plugin too for me.  Same error.  When I get a sku that matches a sku that is part of a variation, I can get and manipulate everything via meta.  I can get the correct product ID via $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );.  The second I ask woocommerce for the $product = new WC_Product( $product_id ); via that call woocommerce throws the exception, not my code.  It's woocommerce that cannot read the data at this point.  I'm opening an issue with woocommerce on this.

Comment: @Dave I suppose it crache too with `$product = wc_get_product($product_id)` …

Comment: @LoicTheAztec It just returns a zero and not an id, but it does not throw an exception, so it is much better handled.

Comment: @Dave When you get some related news about, notify me as it's interesting and it has already happened on other questions / answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CRUD Methods will work ... I Have to load wp-load.php first then I can access all WP Functions inside my cron job run php.file
To trouble shoot I Run it in the Cpanel Terminal or locally using Windows Task scheduler
The cron command is something like

```
cd /home/userNamefolder/public_html && /usr/local/bin/php 
/home/userNamefolder/public_html/wp-   
content/plugins/customPlugin/process_products.php
```

and in the start of my file I run wp load like

```
$wp_load_path = '/home/usernamefolder/public_html/wp-load.php';
// Check if the wp-load.php file exists

// Check if the wp-load.php file exists
if (file_exists($wp_load_path)) {
// Include wp-load.php
require_once $wp_load_path;
error_log('load wp path');
echo('load wp');
} else {
error_log('unable to locate path');
// Handle the case where wp-load.php does not exist
die(dirname(__FILE__));
}
```